# Why is this not continuous/not a homotopy?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider continuous maps from $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Define a family of such maps $F:[0,1]_t \times [0,1]_x \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ by
$$F(t,x) = \begin{cases} x^{1/(1-t)}, & 0\leq t < 1,\\ 0, & t=1.\end{cases}$$
Then $F(0,x)=x$ and $F(1,x)=0$. My intuition says that $F$ should not be continuous since the endpoint $F(t,1)$ sort of "snaps down" at the last moment. On the other hand, each $x \in [0,1)$ eventually settles down near $0$ while the endpoint $F(t,1)$ actually never moves when you consider it in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (in which $0$ and $1$ are equivalent). Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Try investigate the value of $F$ when $(x,t)$ are close to the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks @EricTowers, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is not well-defined. For $t = 1$ you get the undefined expression $1/0$. Moreover, even if you could somehow redefine $F$ for $t = 1$, you get $\lim_{t \to 0} F(t,x) = \lim_{s \to 1} x^{1/s} = x$ which shows that $F$ cannot be continuous in $(x,0)$ when $x \ne 0$.

**Update:**

After the change of the definition of $F$ my above answer is obsolete. Here is a new proof.

Assume that $F :  I \times I \to S = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is continuous. Then also $G : I \times I \to I \times S, G(t,x) = (t,F(t,x))$ would be continuous. Thus $G(I \times I)$ would be compact, hence closed in $I \times S$. But $G(I \times I) = [0,1) \times S \cup \{(1, [0])\}$ which is not closed.

Comment: I mixed up my definition. The first case should be on $0 \leq t < 1$ and then it goes to the zero function at the last instant $t=1$. I don't see the issue with your second point.

Comment: @EthanDlugie After you changed the definition the second point is obsolete ;-)